# How to get full text of a block in Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, google-cloud-vision

I try to use Google Cloud Vision API to detect text of an image. After detecting, I get 1 page and 17 Blocks. I am trying to get text in each blocks and save it in a list, but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("./wwwroot/images/page1.PNG");
ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
var text = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
InvoiceFileModel invoice = new InvoiceFileModel();
List<object> itemList = new List<object>();
foreach (var page in text.Pages)
{
   foreach (var block in page.Blocks)
   {
       string item = string.Join("\n", paragraph.Words);
       itemList.Add(item);
   }
}
```

I would like to know is there any other way to get text. Thanks a lot.